# htmx:afterSettle not working with hx-trigger

Tags: htmx

This code does not trigger a swap event, even though I can see that the afterSettle event is firing in the console.

```
<div id="product-gallery" hx-trigger="htmx:afterSettle" hx-get="{% url 'products' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML">
```

This works, but loops forever of course, with:

```
<div id="product-gallery" hx-trigger="load" hx-get="{% url 'products' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML">
```

I can see from htmx.logAll() that the htmx:afterSettle even is firing, it's just not triggering the above element. Have also tried htmx:afterSwap, which is also logged by logAll()

I'm trying to reload the gallery after a form has been swapped out (the form is inside this parent product-gallery div). Which I was hoping I could achieve by adding a from constraint:

```
<div id="product-gallery" hx-get="{% url 'products' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="afterSettle from:.product-form">
```

Structure is:

```
<div id="product-gallery">
<div id="product-form-1"> 
<form>
...
</form>
</div>
...
</div>
```

Update - it works! Followed solution 3 from https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/:
I added a header to my response in the form update view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    context = dict()
    context['form'] = form
    response = render(self.request, 'form_product.html', context)
    response['HX-Trigger'] = 'productUpdate'
    return response
```

Then I listen for this event in the gallery div:

```
<div id="product-gallery" hx-get="{% url 'products' %}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="productUpdate from:body">
```

The one bit of js I retain is for closing forms when they are valid:

```
htmx.on("htmx:afterSwap", function(evt) {
    const eventIdTarget = evt['target'].id;
    if (eventIdTarget === 'product-gallery') {
        if ($("[id^=product-form] .alert-warning").length === 0) {
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Same question: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/610

Comment: Please explain you use case from a high level perspective. Example: The initial page contains a gallery and foo. The user clicks on bar, then xyz happens. Then ... should be changed.

Comment: @guettli I'm trying to update a gallery of forms after one of these forms has been sucessfully returned from the server. That's why I'm trying to trigger upon afterSettle - I want to update the gallery after a form as been returned from the server, not submitted to it. This matters because the returned form could be changed, and is represented a second time alphabetically in the gallery as a thumbnail with some hover text. So every time a new form is returned, I must update the gallery.

Comment: Please update the question. the text in the comment is hard to read. You can use the enumerated lists for the steps.

Comment: Here are nice docs about "update other element". https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm starting to get it now. I like solution 3 the most (event driven). The reason is that this is a django app, and I don't want to mess with the responses of my views in such a way that would break the django norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have troubles with http redirects, then this might help you:

If you want a response which was triggered via htmx to do a **full page reload**, then you should **not return a http redirect response** (302, aka as HttpResponseRedirect in Django).

You need to set the hx-redirect response header: https://htmx.org/reference/#response_headers

If you set hx-redirect and set the http response code to 302, then htmx will do a redirect on ajax-level (not on the full screen).

Next thing which might confuse new users: if you are used to the old post/redirect/get pattern, then there are good news: This is not needed any more.

If the client sends a http-post, and all data validates, you should return a http 2xx response containing the new HTML. There is no need for the outdated redirect/get dance.

If you think the htmx docs could get improved, then you might want to create a pull request to improve the docs.

Comment: This seemed hard at first, but it was really easy once I got the hang of it. 1) Response header becomes part of DOM after a htmx swap 2) an already-rendered part of the DOM is listening for this header in the body 3) once the header is seen another swap is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't use "afterSettle" like this: `hx-trigger="htmx:afterSettle"`.

If you want to update a second part of the page, then you can use OOB (out-off-band):

> The hx-swap-oob attribute allows you to specify that some content in a **response** should be swapped into the DOM somewhere other than the target, that is "Out of Band". This allows you to piggy back updates to other element updates on a response.

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/

More about [Update other content](http://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why. I can make the gallery listen for form submit events, but that is too early. Only after the form has been returned after settling can I safely update the gallery, that contains the newly updated form. Is OOB the only way I can achieve this?

Comment: *the correct way, I should have said. Not the only way. Theres always another way.

Comment: @wellspokenman up to now most htmx experts are reachable via the discord channel. Maybe post a link to above question there.

Comment: I had a go at the event trigger thing, but it's still not working (have updated question). Solution 3 from this link you shared: https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/ looks like exaclty what I want to do. I have two different Views; one for the form update post, and another for the gallery update get. I want a header from the response of the former to trigger a request for the latter.

Comment: I think you should not return a HttpResponseRedirect, because htmx will first do the redirect and then parse the response of the URL which the redirect redirected to. The outdated post/redirect/get pattern is not needed with htmx. Please provide feedback if this solved your issue.

Comment: oh of course. been staring at this too long. If you write that as the suggested answer I can accept it as the correct one.